# Angular2 routing between 2 different html pages

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have an angular2 application containing a front-end and an admin interface.

The front-end has a set of distinctive front-end styles defined in the index.html.

The admin interface has its own distinct set of styles which (may) conflict with the styles in the front-end.

As such I would like to have an admin.html and a index.html. If the user selects the path /admin/** it displays using the admin.html, otherwise it displays the index.html. Everything else in the application (app modules, services, etc) should be shared.

I have considered using 2 different root components and encapsulating the css - however - most of the styles are in regular css files - and I don't believe it is feasible to associate these with different root components.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you just encapsulate the styles in the components? Angular 2 is a single page app. You should not need and should never use more than one html page (index.html). You can just create different components and specify a stylesheet for each:

**Home Component**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  templateUrl: 'home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.component.css'],
  selector: 'home',
})
export class HomeComponent {}
```

**Admin Component**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  templateUrl: 'admin.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['admin.component.css'],
  selector: 'admin',
})
export class AdminComponent {}
```

Comment: where would my router-outlet go?

Comment: Thanks Bhetzie - I have restructured my component hierarchy as you discussed. It did pose some challenges - and required the use of multiple router-outlets to accomadate the different headers / footers in the frontend and admin interfaces.